# How to integrate an Angular 2 app to another Angular 2 app

Tags: javascript, angular

I have developed a chart library with D3 and Angular 2. It can create a chart when we provide the data source. Now I am implementing a website with Angular 2 and I need to include my chart library into it and draw charts.

How can I integrate my chart library to my app ? Can I integrate it using "dist" folder created when building the application.

Comment: create chart library as ngmodule then you can import module to your site

Comment: @RavinSinghD to create the library as ngmodule I have to publish my code in github. but I don't want to do that. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: no, you no need to publish it to github.create as module and copy the files to your project folder and import from that

Comment: **create as module** means? No idea on how to do that :(